# No sound when using youtube_dl with discord.py voice clients

Tags: python, youtube, discord, discord.py, youtube-dl

I am trying to use youtube_dl with discord.py to play a youtube video in a voice channel. I was following a tutorial on how to do this, and this is what I have so far:

```
import youtube_dl

@client.command()
async def p(ctx, url):
    vc = await discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name="General").connect()

    player = await vc.create_ytdl_player(url)
    player.start()
```

The problem is that the bot connects to the voice channel just fine, but no audio plays. I do not get any sort of error messages, I just get silence. Also, youtube_dl does not have any documentation from what I can see, so I am at a loss.

Comment: What verison of discord.py are you using?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Sorry for the late reply! I'm using version 1.2.3

Comment: See this example bot: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/master/examples/basic_voice.py